# How can React componets use bootstrap responsive columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Let's say we want a reusable component like this:

```
render: function () {
    return (
    <div className="form-group">
        <label className="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <div className="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" className="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Apparently, the `className`s are design specific. I think the component should know as least design.

But if I set the props while rendering like this:

```
<C class1="form-group" class2="col-md-3 col-sm-4" class3="col-md-9 col-sm-8" class4="form-control">
```

That's so verbose and unmaintainable. So what's your practice while doing responsive classes?

Comment: Add it to the render method of course.

Comment: That does not help either. I think the inner structure of a component should be transparent to outer world. That's why we use it in the first place.

Comment: No, classes shouldn't be a part of props unless you specifically need to change classes depending on usecases then you should do `<C classes={classesObject} />`.

Comment: What's the point of a component if you want to be able to change everything about it from the outside? Components should be black boxes as much as possible, or you're asking for maintenance trouble.